# Play audio with mp3 artwork in iOS web app

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, web, html5-audio

I'm interested in building an iOS web app (iPhone) which will play audio files (mp3) and display artwork as the music is playing when the phone is locked. Is this supported in the latest versions of iOS (8.1), and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Where you able to do it?